# Exclude values based on duplicate values in onecolumns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data in a format like this from SQL query

| No | ID | Value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | xx | 09-Aug-22 |
| 1 | A | xx | 10-Aug-22 |
| 2 | B | xx | 09-Aug-22 |
| 2 | B | yy | 10-Aug-22 |
| 3 | C | xx | 10-Aug-22 |

Out of this I want to remove the data which is duplicate in column Value and Single row for same NO and ID
SO My final output should be like

| No | ID | Value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | B | xx | 09-Aug-22 |
| 2 | B | yy | 10-Aug-22 |

How this can be achieved

Comment: You need to better explain the logic by which you arrive at this result set.

Comment: so is this your requirement.  Based on NO and ID if there is  a single row remove it,  if there are multiple rows only display the rows if all the Values are different?

Comment: Yes @Bryan Dellinger

Answer (score 1):

You may use window finctions to calculate number of rows per group and then filter out rows you do not want.

> ```
> with prep as (
>   select
>     t.*
>     /*Identify No with more that one row*/
>     , count(1) over(
>         partition by no
>       ) as count_per_group
>     /*Identify rows with duplicates*/
>     , count(1) over(
>         partition by no, id, value
>       ) as count_duplicates
>   from t
> )
> select No, ID, Value, dt
> from prep
> where count_per_group > 1
>   and count_duplicates = 1
> ```
>
> | NO | ID | VALUE | DT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | B | xx | 09-Aug-22 |
> | 2 | B | yy | 10-Aug-22 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1dc30be4278528b1b1cab480df55c71b)*

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it:

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (no,
  3           id,
  4           VALUE,
  5           datum)
  6     AS
  7        (SELECT 1, 'A', 'xx', DATE '2022-08-09' FROM DUAL
  8         UNION ALL
  9         SELECT 1, 'A', 'xx', DATE '2022-08-10' FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT 2, 'B', 'xx', DATE '2022-08-09' FROM DUAL
 12         UNION ALL
 13         SELECT 2, 'B', 'yy', DATE '2022-08-10' FROM DUAL
 14         UNION ALL
 15         SELECT 3, 'C', 'xx', DATE '2022-08-10' FROM DUAL),
```

Count number of distinct values per `no, id` and total number of rows per `no, id`:

```
 16     temp
 17     AS
 18        (  SELECT no,
 19                  id,
 20                  COUNT (DISTINCT VALUE) cnt_dv,
 21                  COUNT (*) cnt
 22             FROM test
 23         GROUP BY no, id)
```

Finally, exclude rows for which total number of rows is `1` (that's `ID = C`) and rows for which number of distinct values is different from total number of rows (that's `A`):

```
 24    SELECT *
 25      FROM test
 26     WHERE (no, id, VALUE) NOT IN (SELECT no, id, VALUE
 27                                     FROM temp
 28                                    WHERE    cnt = 1
 29                                          OR cnt_dv <> cnt)
 30  ORDER BY no, id, VALUE;

        NO ID VALUE      DATUM
---------- -- ---------- ----------
         2 B  xx         09.08.2022
         2 B  yy         10.08.2022

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT OVER` to see whether there is more than one value for a no/id.

```
select no, id, value, dat
from
(
  select
    no, id, value, dat,
    count(distinct value) over (partition by no, id) as cnt
  from mytable
)
where cnt > 1
order by no, id, dat;
```

(I've replaced date with dat, because date is a keyword in SQL. Put in your real column name there.)